# Custom Field to post_title

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-field

I have a custom post type that only uses custom fields. I am trying to find a way to create a post_title since it will be blank otherwise. I have the following code which successfully does this when I update a post. Is there a way to make this happen when a post is initially published, as opposed to saved on an update?

```
function custom_post_type_title($post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'my-custom-post-type') {
        $name = get_post_custom_values('custom-field-to-use');
        $title = $name[0];
        $where = array('ID' => $post_id);
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_title' => $title), $where);
    } 
}

add_action('save_post', 'custom_post_type_title');
```

Comment: Hi, Have you tried the `add_action('transition_post_status', 'custom_post_type_title');` instead of `save_post` hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [**save_post**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook.

> `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or
>   updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc,
>   or post by email.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse254017_set_post_title', 10, 2 );

function wpse254017_set_post_title ( $post_id, $post ){
    //This temporarily removes action to prevent infinite loops
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse254017_set_post_title' );

    if ( 'my-custom-post-type' !== $post->post_type )
        return;

    //GET THE CUSTOM FIELD
    $post_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'apt_first_name', true );

    //UPDATE TITLE
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $post_title,
    ));

    //redo action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse254017_set_post_title', 10, 2 );
}
```

The hook can also be re-written specifying the post_type **`save_post_{post_type}`**, this way you don't have the hook running on all post_types.

```
add_action( 'save_post_{post_type}', 'wpse254017_set_post_title' );

function wpse254017_set_post_title ( $post_id ){
    //This temporarily removes action to prevent infinite loops
    remove_action( 'save_post_{post_type}', 'wpse254017_set_post_title' );

    //GET THE CUSTOM FIELD
    $post_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'apt_first_name', true );

    //UPDATE TITLE
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $post_title,
    ));

    //redo action
    add_action( 'save_post_{post_type}', 'wpse254017_set_post_title');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same result. Will save post_title upon update, and not initial save.

Comment: Which did you use and have you tried changing the priority?

Comment: I tried save_post_{post_type}, I tried changing the priority as well but no good.

Comment: I just tried your first solution and that worked like a charm, however. Thanks!

Comment: Not enough reputation to upvote :(